# Year to date running total column based on values within a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a query in a database using SQL Azure, which returns a set of sales figures, month by month, for a set of offices and staff within those offices, as in the image below:
[image]
The query which returns this is called vwOfficeAndNegSalesTotals and looks like this:

```
SELECT OfficeID, 
    DATENAME(Month,PipelineDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(Year,PipelineDate) as [PipelineMonth],
    OfficeName, 
    Negotiator, 
    Status,
    SUM(Fee) as FeeValue
FROM vwBankingProjections
GROUP BY OfficeID,
    DATENAME(Month,PipelineDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(Year,PipelineDate),
    OfficeName, 
    Negotiator, 
    Status, 
    DATEPART(Month,PipelineDate),
    DATEPART(YEAR,PipelineDate)
```

I need to add another column, which provides a running total of FeeValue for the year to date for the Negotiator in that row, with the year "to date" meaning up to and including the month of that row. Additionally, it should only total the FeeValue where the status is Payment received.

So, it would return something like this:

[image: Figures including YTD values]

As you can tell from the structure of vwOfficeAndNegSalesTotals, the query upon which it is based (vwBankingProjections) does include actual dates, rather than just the text Month + Year - these dates are in the PipelineDate column.

My first attempt got me a total for the year which viewing a row for May 2016 (at time of writing) would be the year to date, but it needs to only show the total for the year to the date mentioned in that row (so if viewing a row for April 2016, would be the total from Jan - April 2016). In case it's of any help, here's what I came up with for that:

```
SELECT OfficeID, 
    DATENAME(Year,PipelineDate) as [PipelineYear],
    OfficeName, 
    Negotiator, 
    SUM(Fee) as YTDFee
FROM vwBankingProjections
WHERE Status IN ('Payment Received')
GROUP BY OfficeID, 
    DATENAME(Year,PipelineDate),
    OfficeName, 
    Negotiator
```

If anyone can help, I'd be grateful, as this is a bit beyond my skill-set.

Thanks a lot

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM() OVER().

Create and populate table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sales
(
    OfficeID int NOT NULL,
    PipelineMonth date NOT NULL
        CHECK (DAY(PipelineMonth) = 1),
    OfficeName nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Negotiator nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    [Status] nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    FeeValue int NOT NULL,
    FeeValueReceived AS IIF([Status] = N'Payment received', FeeValue, 0)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Sales (OfficeID, PipelineMonth, OfficeName, Negotiator, [Status], FeeValue)
    VALUES
    (1, '2016-01-01', N'London', N'Fred', N'Payment received', 5000),
    (1, '2016-01-01', N'London', N'Fred', N'Completed', 4800),
    (1, '2016-01-01', N'London', N'Kate', N'Payment received', 5980),
    (1, '2016-01-01', N'London', N'Kate', N'Completed', 7000),
    (1, '2016-01-01', N'London', N'Bob', N'Payment received', 9250),
    (2, '2016-01-01', N'Birmingham', N'Jo', N'Payment received', 7870),
    (2, '2016-01-01', N'Birmingham', N'Kathryn', N'Payment received', 3690),
    (2, '2016-01-01', N'Birmingham', N'Kathryn', N'Completed', 8545),
    (1, '2016-02-01', N'London', N'Fred', N'Payment received', 6500),
    (1, '2016-02-01', N'London', N'George', N'Completed', 2575),
    (1, '2016-02-01', N'London', N'George', N'Payment received', 7500),
    (1, '2016-02-01', N'London', N'Kate', N'Payment received', 8393),
    (1, '2016-02-01', N'London', N'Bob', N'Payment received', 6125);
```

Then make a SELECT statement with SUM() OVER().

```
SELECT OfficeID, PipelineMonth, OfficeName, Negotiator, [Status], FeeValue,
        SUM(FeeValueReceived) OVER (PARTITION BY OfficeID, Negotiator, YEAR(PipelineMonth) ORDER BY PipelineMonth, [Status] DESC, FeeValue DESC) AS 'YTD'
    FROM dbo.Sales
    ORDER BY PipelineMonth, OfficeID, Negotiator, [Status] DESC, FeeValue DESC
```

[image]

See Books Online > OVER Clause (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: That's perfect - thank you. I've read the Books Online link you sent, and although it does help, I find it really hard to understand some of the content. For example: 

_If ROWS/RANGE is specified and <window frame preceding> is used for <window frame extent> (short syntax) then this specification is used for the window frame boundary starting point and CURRENT ROW is used for the boundary ending point. For example “ROWS 5 PRECEDING” is equal to “ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW”. _

I'm sure that I'm just being dense, but is there anywhere else you'd recommend I might find help?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Books Online isn't always easy. The OVER clause is quite complicated at first sight, particularly the ROW OR RANGE part. See Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals by Itzik Ben-Gan > Chapter 7: Beyond the Fundamentals of Querying > Window Functions.

Comment: Also he's written a follow up book: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 High Performance T-SQL Using Windows Functions (Developer Reference). I haven't got that one, but it's probably good.

Answer (score 0):

RichardCL has a solid approach.  If you need a true RunningTotal, see the following examples in https://devjef.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/calculating-running-totals/